# Is there any way to set a select dropdown to display its data downwards instead of upwards?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms

I'm mapping a list with some data in an input select dropdown, but the "select" is displaying data from the top of the screen until the input select, instead of starting to display data from the select input downwards. I will attach a screenshot of how it looks like and my code for that input select.

[Image of how the select is showing up the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XneKg.jpg)

```
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
            <Form.Label>{typeSelection}</Form.Label>  {/* value that sets the name of the label dinamically once an option is chosen in the previous dropDown */}
            <Form.Select defaultValue="Choose...">
              {
                consultSelection > -1 &&
                (
                  cdrTypeRequest[consultSelection].api.map((item, i)=>(
                    <option key={"name" + i} value={i}>{item.name}</option>
                  ))
                )
              }
            </Form.Select>
          </Form.Group>
```

I have no issues with the data itself but how it is being displayed on the dropdown, as it supposes to be from the input select field downwards, as I normally see it works. I'm not sure if it displaying it in that way because of the amount of data the select is trying to display? I've already test in other browsers and still displaying it in the same way?

I would appreciate your help and any clarification on how this elements work! Thank you!

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: I'm using React and I did the form with Bootstrap v5